# Как в переменую передать функцию

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void * input(char InData[1024]){
    char *str = malloc(sizeof( char ));
    printf(InData);
    fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    char a[] = input("Hello:");
    printf(a);
}
```

какой тип должен быть у переменой что-бы она  принимала функцию ?

Решено

код

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void * input(char InData[1024]){
    char *str = malloc(sizeof( char ));
    printf(InData);
    fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    char * a = input("Your name?:");
    printf("Hello %s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: она ведь принимает результат функции?

Comment: @azlov Да по идей должна но компилятор ругается на строк char a[] = input("Hello") и в ошибке пишет error: invalid initializer

Comment: Второй параметр `main` нестандартный, хотя это меньшая из проблем :)

Comment: *какой тип должен быть у переменой что-бы она принимала функцию ?* — тип указатель, а не массив. Вы же возвращаете указатель

Comment: @kombat ответы — в ответы ниже, а не в сам вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для коректной компиляции переменая должна иметь тип `char *`  , выделения памяти должно происходить по размеру данных. И не забудте высвободить память после ее использования.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char * input(char * InData)
{
    size_t len = strlen(InData);
    char *str = malloc(len + 1);
    snprintf(str,len, "%s",InData);
    fgets(str, len, stdin);
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char * a = input("Hello:");
    printf("%s", a);
    free(a);
 }
```

Comment: `printf` с 1 аргументом не лучшая идея

Comment: @dIm0n  да в пример не совсем понятна логика.

Comment: Я не про логику, а про это https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string